# Not finding hash key values with regex

Tags: ruby, regex, hash

I have a hash that will have entries similar to entry1, entry2, etc and I'm trying to count how many times they appear but I also have an entry similar to entry_hello.  So when I try to count how many times they appear the 'entry_hello' is also counted. I have this code here to see if each entry matches or not but this doesn't work as I expected.

```
hash = {}
hash['entry'] = 'Test1'
hash['entry_date'] = 'Test2'
hash['entry2'] = 'Test3'

hash.each do |x|
puts x.to_s.scan(/entry\d?$/).count
end
```

But in this case nothing is found, but without the `$` the 'entry_hello' is counted.  I've tried with strings and this works but when I try it with hash keys it doesn't.  I don't understand why it doesn't work, and would like to know ether how to get this to work or another method to do this.

UPDATE:
For anyone who cares: The reason my code didn't work is because `x` in this case was the key/value pair so `x` didn't equal 'entry' or 'entry2' but instead equaled 'entryTest1' or 'entry2Test3'.

Sawa's answer works since the the underscore in `hash.count{|k, _| k =~ /\Aentry\d?\z/}` is meant to indicate that while the closure takes a second argument, it will not be assigned a value.

I'm probably going to go ahead and use `hash.keys.count{|k| k =~  /\Aentry\d?\z/ }` since this is more understandable to me.  The key here is the `key's` part as now you are only looking at the keys of the hash not both keys and values.

Comment: I'm using ruby 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [i386-mingw32]

Comment: I didn't figure out this myself but the credit instead goes to one of my friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hash.count{|k, _| k =~ /\Aentry\d?\z/}
```

`'entry_date'` will match `/entry\d?/` without `\z` or `$`.

Comment: Could you explain why the code in the question is not working?

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I also second dan1111's question about why my original didn't work. I assume part of the problem was using the `$` end of line character verses the `\z` end of string?

Comment: It does not make difference here, but semantically, end of string makes more sense here than end of line.